# XPath condition that accepts non-numerical characters

Tags: xpath, conditional-statements, sap-pi, sap-xi

I am currently constructing an XPath condition in SAP PI (receiver determination object) which should either route the message to receiver 1 or receiver 2.

The given documentID values that the business sends are as follows.

Receiver 1 receives messages within below documentID range

```
Range: "F00" to "F99"
```

Receiver 2 receives messages within below documentID range

```
Range: "FA0" to "FZ9"
```

Sample condition that I can think of, but not sure if this will work or if the logic is correct. Follow up question too, does greater/less than signs accept non-numerical characters?

Condition for Receiver 1

```
(/p1:Upload/ContainerEvent[WorkAssignmentID >= F00] EX  AND /p1:Upload/ContainerEvent[WorkAssignmentID <= F99] EX )
```

Condition for Receiver 2

```
(/p1:Upload/ContainerEvent[WorkAssignmentID >= FA0] EX  AND /p1:Upload/ContainerEvent[WorkAssignmentID <= FZ9] EX )
```

I am also thinking if substring can be used in XPath. Feel free to provide your inputs. Thanks

Regards,
Charles Tan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your follow-up question ("does greater/less than signs accept non-numerical characters?"): in XPath 1.0, no, greater-than/less-than operate only on numerics. This changes in XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

**Pure XPath 1.0 solution:**

> Receiver 1 receives messages within below documentID range Range: F00
>   to F99

```
/*/Upload/ContainerEvent
               [WorkAssignmentId
                 [string-length() = 3]
                 [starts-with(., 'F')][substring(.,2,2) >= 0][99 >= substring(.,2,2)]
                ]/EX
```

> Receiver 2 receives messages within below documentID range Range: FA0
>   to FZ9

```
/*/Upload/ContainerEvent
               [WorkAssignmentId
                   [string-length() = 3]
                   [starts-with(., 'F')] 
                   [26 > string-length(
                            translate('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',substring(.,2,1), ''))]
                   [substring(.,3,1) >= 0][9 >= substring(.,3,1)]
                ]/EX
```

**Here is XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "/*/Upload/ContainerEvent
               [WorkAssignmentId
                 [string-length() = 3]
                 [starts-with(., 'F')][substring(.,2,2) >= 0][99 >= substring(.,2,2)]
                ]/EX"/>
==============================
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "/*/Upload/ContainerEvent
               [WorkAssignmentId
                   [string-length() = 3]
                   [starts-with(., 'F')] 
                   [26 > string-length(
                            translate('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',substring(.,2,1), ''))]
                   [substring(.,3,1) >= 0][9 >= substring(.,3,1)]
                ]/EX"/>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML source document** (none provided):

```
<p1>
    <Upload>
        <ContainerEvent>
            <WorkAssignmentId>F13</WorkAssignmentId>
            <EX>F13</EX>
        </ContainerEvent>
        <ContainerEvent>
            <WorkAssignmentId>F99</WorkAssignmentId>
            <EX>F99</EX>
        </ContainerEvent>
        <ContainerEvent>
            <WorkAssignmentId>E15</WorkAssignmentId>
            <EX>E15</EX>
        </ContainerEvent>
        <ContainerEvent>
            <WorkAssignmentId>FA7</WorkAssignmentId>
            <EX>FA7</EX>
        </ContainerEvent>
        <ContainerEvent>
            <WorkAssignmentId>FZ9</WorkAssignmentId>
            <EX>FZ9</EX>
        </ContainerEvent>
        <ContainerEvent>
            <WorkAssignmentId>FAB</WorkAssignmentId>
            <EX>FAB</EX>
        </ContainerEvent>
    </Upload>
</p1>
```

**The wanted result is produced**:

```
<EX>F13</EX>
<EX>F99</EX>
==============================
<EX>FA7</EX>
<EX>FZ9</EX>
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! It was very helpful. My final working conditions are below (/p1:Upload/OrderLineEvent[string-length(WorkAssignmentID) = 10 and starts-with(WorkAssignmentID, 'F') and number(substring(WorkAssignmentID,2))>=0 and number(substring(WorkAssignmentID,2))<=999999999] EX )